# canOpenURL: failed for URL: "instagram://app" - error: "(null)" error arrives when instagram app is not installed

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram

Instagram sharing is supporting in my iOS app. But when instagram app is not installed then the error has arrived -

```
canOpenURL: failed for URL: "instagram://app" - error: "(null)"
```

Here some code I have used

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) 
    {

    }
```

I have use LSApplicationQueriesSchemes scheme in app's .plist

```
 <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>instagram</string>
</array>
```

So now what is the solution? 
Can't I post image to instagram when instagram app is not installed?

Comment: How would you expect a custom URL scheme to work when the app supporting that scheme is **not** installed?

Comment: r u tried this in simulator or device

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I think it should work on Symbian I guess :D

Comment: Geez you guys are harsh. Take the language barrier aside, what the guy is actually asking is if there is a way to post an image to Instagram in case the user doesn't have the app installed. The most obvious answer would be through the Instagram API however that capability is not available by design. So the answer to the question is unless you have the app installed, you will be unable to post pictures to Instagram via a third party app.

Comment: You can use some open source UIActivity based implementations such as https://github.com/AquaSupport/AQSInstagramActivity